# "When did you go there?" vs "When you went there?"

Tags: wh-questions

Could someone help me to understand the difference between these two sentences.

- When did you go there?
- When you went there?

What is the correct way of using these forms?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be asked on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I think it should be kept open and pinned as an example of a question you had better be able to answer if you post here.

Answer (score 2):

You can make an *IN SITU* question by making a normal sentence and replacing the information you don't know with a *wh-* word:

1. You're meeting *who*?
2. You can see *what*?
3. You went there *when*?

If you want to make a normal question, you need to move the *wh-* word to the beginning of the sentence. In this situation, you will need to use subject-auxiliary inversion. The subject and auxiliary will change places after the question word:

- Who **are you** meeting?
- What **can you** see?

In example (3), the in situ  question has no auxiliary verb: *You went where?*. We cannot use *went* as an auxiliary verb. We need a proper auxiliary. In this situation, we need to use the auxiliary verb *DO*:

- <del>When **you went** there?</del> (wrong)
- When **did you** go there?

**Note**: Notice, though, that if the *wh-* word is already at the front in the in situ question, we do not need to use subject auxiliary inversion:

- *Who* went there?

Comment: However, "When you went there?" can be a confirmatory question. "The Pope's in Rome. I saw him recently." "When you went there?" (A bit contrived, but examples often are)

Comment: @AndrewLeach: And note that "When you went there?" in that bit-contrived example would be pronounced with an intonation **completely** different from the intonation it would get if it were intended as a question (by a non-native speaker, probly; native speakers don't normally emit questions like this).

Comment: @JohnLawler That (with your other comment) is precisely the reason I edited the question and left it open.

Comment: @Andrew: OK, fair enough. My answer's here, too; I didn't try to be complete, only correct and fairly clear. There are many many more facts and varieties to add to this information about English questions. Tag questions are fun, and threat questions (_So, you're a Republican, are you?_), multiple Wh-questions (_Who did what to whom?_), Question intonation alone (***Eighteen** under par??? You're kidding*), not to mention response variables like "Uh-huh" and "Uh-uh" and "Mm-hmm". There's a vast literature on questions, and plenty of syntax. But strange logic; questions can't be true or false.

Answer (score 2):

The question is about turning statements into questions. There are lots of ways, and different kinds of resulting questions. It makes the most sense to me if it's looked at on two levels:

1. ***Yes/No* Questions** -- The lower level, with binary possibilities only.

   - Several offshoots, 
     including Neg-swap tags
     *He saw her, didn't he? / He didn't see her, did he?*
     Some features (starting with a sentence in the present or past tense)
   - Y/N questions normally have subject-auxiliary inversion
     (*He is going* => *Is he going?*)
   - Inverted Y/N questions take *Do*-Support if there's no auxiliary
     (*He went* => *Did he go?*)
   - Y/N questions have rising intonation at the end
     (symbolized by a question mark in writing)

So the rule for forming a Y/N question is:

- If there isn't an auxiliary, insert *do* and change the main verb to an infinitive form.
- Move the auxiliary verb (or *do*, if it's been supplied, in front of the subject.
- Add question intonation at the end.

> (By the way, this is just a description of how sentences are arranged, and related to one another. 
>   It doesn't represent -- it isn't **intended** to represent -- what speakers actually do when they talk.)

2. ***Wh*- Questions** -- Higher level, specific information, uses the Y/N rule above.
        Several offshoots,  including *In Situ* questions, [as @Auraucaria points out](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/239040/15299).
           Some features (starting with a sentence in the present or past tense):
           • *Wh*-questions always contain a *Wh*-word specifying the  information requested
              -- *who, what, which, when, where, why, how* (plus *whether*; *whence, whither,

                 whereof, wherewith*, etc. are obsolete forms of *where*)
           • If the *Wh*-word is the subject, ***Stop***.
              The *In Situ* question is a correctly-formed *Wh*-question.
           • Otherwise, form a *Yes/No* question (using the rule in part 1)
              from the *In Situ* question.  (including *Do*-Support, as needed)
           • Then move the Wh-word to the beginning of the question,
              before the fronted auxiliary verb.

So the rule for a *Wh*-question is

- Insert the *Wh*-word for the unknown information (*He saw `X`* => *He saw who*)
- If the *Wh*-word is the subject, ***Stop*** (add a question mark if writing).
- Otherwise, make a Y/N question, using the rule in part 1
         (*He saw who* =>  *Did he see who*)
- And move the *Wh*-word to the front (*Did he see who* => *Who did he see?*)

Comment: A comprehensive answer to an important question. I'd just add a very minor addendum that if the *wh-* word is *any* part of a subject phrase, not necessarily the entire subject, we don't S-A don't invert. So for example with questions beginning "*Which pen* is the ..." and so forth.

Comment: Do you think that maybe we apply the S-A rule and then subsequently move the subject NP to the front when the *wh-* word is part of the subject?  (So it looks the same but has had both rules applied)

Comment: Who knows? Everybody has their own grammar, and they're different in details, even if they produce output that works. No doubt some people actually do follow these rules as stated, and others have a completely different approach. That's why I added the parenthetical comment after stating Rule 1 above.